# Wanting to build an automotive grade solid state relay center

Tags: power

I am wanting to build a solid state relay and fuse center for motorcycle applications.  It will be used to drive the positive side of all components, such as fuel pump, lights, solenoids, exc.  I would like to use fets to do this.  The imputs to turn them on are negative or ground.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 4):

What you are describing is called a "high side switch".  It is simple enough to create one with a P-channel MOSFET.  Given that your inputs are "active low" - i.e., when "on" they are connected to ground, and when "off" they are at your input voltage (12V?), the schematic is even simpler.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feSM2m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Q1 is kept normally off by R1 pulling the gate up to +12V.  When the switch is closed (or whatever "low" input you have is activated) the gate is pulled down through R2 (not strictly needed but good to have) and the MOSFET turns on.  That then allows power to flow through to *Load +*.

Diode D1 and C1 are to absorb any back EMF from an inductive load (e.g., solenoid) - they can be omitted from a non-inductive load, like a headlight.

I'll leave you to shop around for a suitable MOSFET and other components with the right voltage and current ratings for your application.

Comment: Yeah, I was worried about inductive loads and turning off. Does the body diode take care of that?  Or would a reverse diode still be useful?

Comment: A reverse diode for inductive loads is always going to be useful.  I'll add one.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold The body diode is the wrong polarity. Remember inductors like to keep the current flowing in the same direction- so for a high side driver the voltage on turn-off will shoot down below chassis ground until it either rings with the capacitance or the MOSFET avalanches.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany,  yeah thanks for the correction. (I guess I'm not suppose to say thanks, but what's the protocol for acknowledging a mistake?)

Comment: Dunno. You could delete the question, but I think it's actually a FAQ, so leaving it in makes more sense to leave it unless Majenko wants to incorporate it into his answer, in which case we can delete these comments.

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle  I know the voltages I need but I am also very new to electrical circuits.  What size cap would I need in c1?  Voltages can spike as high as 50v.